# Concatenate columns in data frame

Tags: r

We have brands data in a column/variable which is delimited by semicolon(;). Our task is to split these column data to multiple columns which we were able to do with the following syntax.

Attached the data as Screen shot.
[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxOOg.png)

Here is the R code:

```
x<-dataset$Pref_All
point<-df %>% separate(x, c("Pref_01","Pref_02","Pref_03","Pref_04","Pref_05"), ";")
point[is.na(point)] <- ""
```

However our question is: We have this type of brands data in more than 10 to 15 columns and if we use the above syntax the maximum number of columns to be split is to be decided on the number of brands each column holds (which we manually calculated and taken as 5 columns). 
We would like to know is there any way where we can write the code in a dynamic way such that it should calculate the maximum number of brands each column holds and accordingly it should create those many new columns in a data frame. for e.g. 
Pref_01,Pref_02,Pref_03,Pref_04,Pref_05.

the preferred output is given as a screen shot. 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtGxS.png)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The best solution here is to not store CSV data in your data frame as you have done.  As you will see from the answer below (assuming someone answers), it gets messy to normalize your data after the fact.

Comment: you should supply for a reproducible example if you seek for useful answers

Answer (score 0):

x <- c("Swift;Baleno;Ciaz;Scross;Brezza", "Baleno;swift;celerio;ignis", "Scross;Baleno;celerio;brezza", "", "Ciaz;Scross;Brezza")

strsplit(x,";")

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                Pref_All = c("S;B;C;S;B",
                             "B;S;C;I",
                             "S;B;C;B",
                             " ",
                             "C;S;B"))
x$Pref_All <- as.character(levels(x$Pref_All))[x$Pref_All]
final_df <- x %>%
        tidyr::separate(Pref_All, c(paste0("Pref_0", 1:b[[which.max(b)]])), ";")
final_df$ID <- x$Pref_All
final_df <- rename(final_df, Pref_All = ID)
final_df[is.na(final_df)] <- ""


   Pref_All Pref_01 Pref_02 Pref_03 Pref_04 Pref_05
1 S;B;C;S;B       S       B       C       S       B
2   B;S;C;I       B       S       C       I        
3   S;B;C;B       S       B       C       B        
4                                                  
5     C;S;B       C       S       B
```

The trick for the column names is given by `paste0` going from 1 to the maximum number of brands in your data!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `str_split()` which returns a list of character vectors. From that, we can work out the max number of preferences in the dataframe and then apply over it a function to add the missing elements.

```
df=data.frame("id"=1:5, 
          "Pref_All"=c("brand1", "brand1;brand2;brand3", "", "brand2;brand4", "brand5"))

spl = str_split(df$Pref_All, ";")
# Find the max number of preferences
maxl = max(unlist(lapply(spl, length)))
# Add missing values to each element of the list
spl = lapply(spl, function(x){c(x, rep("", maxl-length(x)))})
# Bind each element of the list in a data.frame
dfr = data.frame(do.call(rbind, spl))
# Rename the columns
names(dfr) = paste0("Pref_", 1:maxl)
print(dfr)

#    Pref_1    Pref_2    Pref_3
#1   brand1              
#2   brand1    brand2    brand3
#3                     
#4   brand2    brand4       
#5   brand5
```